# How to get uint256 from smart contract without signer

Tags: solidity, web3js, ethers.js, react

I have a simple smart contract method that returns the current token Id minted.

```
    function getCurrentId() public view returns (uint256) {
      return _tokenIds.current();
    }
```

it works just good when i've my wallet connected. But im not sure how to use this method without the wallet connected (or provider), because it returns always undefined if i've not connected my wallet.

What I've noticed so far:

When i have connected my wallet, "library" from useWeb3React() exists, otherwise returns undefined. Idk if i need to set a default provider at the beginning of the application

I'm using web3react